# How do I add a custom rule into customRequest laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web

Is there a way to use the Custom Validation Rules https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

when using the Form Request?

I do not see it anywhere in the docs, and only similar questions on the web with no answer.

Example:

php artisan make:rule Uppercase

**CustomRequest.php**

```
use App\Rules\Uppercase;

protected $rules = [

      'Names' => ['required','string', new Uppercase],
]
```

**UserController.php**

```
public funcion store(CustomRequest $Request)
{

}
```

Any ideas anyone?

message Constant expression contains invalid operations
exception   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
file    C:\xampp\htdocs\jireh\app\Http\Requests\CustomRequest.php
line: 22

Comment: Yes. What you did should work. Are there any errors you're getting or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How add Custom Validation Rules when using Form Request Validation in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793716/how-add-custom-validation-rules-when-using-form-request-validation-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @MahdiYounesi 
is not the same This works for laravel 5.4, so I want to do php artisan make: rule UpperCase and enter in the array $ rules [
   'Names' => ['required', 'string', new Uppercase],
]

Comment: Add your custom rule to the question. (App\Rules\Uppercase)