# How to validate that a field must be true if another field is false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Below is a snippet of my validation currently:

```
'independent_financial_advisor' => 'required|boolean',
'understand_objective' => 'required|boolean',
'confirm_objective' => 'required|boolean',
'understand_term_held' => 'required|boolean',
'tax_relief' => 'required|boolean',
```

I need to validate that when `independent_financial_advisor` is false, the remaining 4 fields below must be true. I could not find any Laravel rule which could do this so I thought about using a closure to create a custom rule.

The issue with this is that I don't know how to reference another field in a closure to check its value.

What is the best way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: Seems this ought to be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793716/how-add-custom-validation-rules-when-using-form-request-validation-in-laravel-5?rq=1

Comment: @Nick Came across it before but after re-reading it, i've managed to get this to work with my form. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a custom validation rule called `true_if_reference_is_false` and passed a parameter to it which is `independent_financial_advisor`.

So the validation looks like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'independent_financial_advisor' => 'required|boolean',
    'understand_objective' => 'required|boolean|true_if_reference_is_false:independent_financial_advisor',
    'confirm_objective' => 'required|boolean|true_if_reference_is_false:independent_financial_advisor',
    'understand_term_held' => 'required|boolean|true_if_reference_is_false:independent_financial_advisor',
    'tax_relief' => 'required|boolean|true_if_reference_is_false:independent_financial_advisor'
]);
```

You need to define this validation rule in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`
Import Facade Validator.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

And define the rule in the `boot` method:

```
Validator::extend('true_if_reference_is_false', function ($key, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $request = request();
    $keyReference = $parameters[0];
    if ($request->has($parameters[0]) && $request->$keyReference == false)
        return (bool)$request->$key;
    else
        return true;
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

```
'independent_financial_advisor' => 'required|boolean',
'understand_objective' => 'boolean|required_if:independent_financial_advisor,0,false',
'confirm_objective' => 'boolean|required_if:independent_financial_advisor,0,false',
'understand_term_held' => 'boolean|required_if:independent_financial_advisor,0,false',
'tax_relief' => 'boolean|required_if:independent_financial_advisor,0,false',
```

For more validation rules, check laravel documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: Sorry if I've got this wrong but required_if just ensures that the field is required. My four fields are always required regardless of if its value is true or false.

Answer (score 3):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'tax_relief'=>['required','in:true']
            ]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json($validator->errors());
}
```

Comment: Please add an brief explanation of what you've done in your answer.

Comment: It only works if the boolean is a String "false" or "true"

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel 8, I solved this with the following:

```php
// MyFormRequest.php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'bool_attrib_1' => [
            'required',
            'bool',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (! $value && ! request('bool_attrib_2')) {
                    $fail('You must select either Bool Attrib 1 or Bool Attrib 2.');
                }
            },
        ],
        'bool_attrib_2' => [
            'required',
            'bool',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (! $value && ! request('bool_attrib_1')) {
                    $fail('You must select either Bool Attrib 1 or Bool Attrib 2.');
                }
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem today and solved it with a [conditional validation closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) (as it's only used once throughout the app).

Basically the user must mark either the `phone` or `email` field as required. They can both be `true` or only one can be `true`, but the **cannot** both be `false`.

The trick is to `use` the `request` object in the closure to gain access to the other field that needs to be part of the validation check. The fields are part of an `array` [casted property](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting), that's why it has the `.`'s.

```
           'required_order_fields.phone' => [
                Rule::in(["true", "false"]),
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                    if ($value === "false" && $request->input('required_order_fields.email') === "false") {
                        $fail('The '.$attribute.' must be required if the email customer field is not required');
                    }
                },
            ],
            'required_order_fields.email' => [
                Rule::in(["true", "false"]),
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                    if ($value === "false" && $request->input('required_order_fields.phone') === "false") {
                        $fail('The '.$attribute.' must be required if the phone customer field is not required');
                    }
                },
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Validator::extend('true_if_reference_is_false', function ($key, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $request = request();
        $keyReference = $parameters[0];
        if ($request->has($parameters[0]) && $request->$keyReference == false)
            return (bool)$request->$key;
        else
            return true;
    });

    Validator::extend('false_if_reference_is_true', function ($key, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $request = request();
        $keyReference = $parameters[0];
        if ($request->has($parameters[0]) && $request->$keyReference == true)
            return !(bool)$request->$key;
        else
            return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution using **Using Laravel 8+**

You can use [acccepted_if validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-accepted-if)

`accepted_if:another_field,value,...`

So this can be applied simply like that

```php
[
'independent_financial_advisor' => 'required|boolean',
'understand_objective' => 'required|boolean|accepted_if:independent_financial_advisor,false',
'confirm_objective' => 'required|boolean|accepted_if:independent_financial_advisor,false',
'understand_term_held' => 'required|boolean|accepted_if:independent_financial_advisor,false',
'tax_relief' => 'required|boolean|accepted_if:independent_financial_advisor,false',
]
```