# Handling validation errors coming from a Request

Tags: laravel

I'm having some troubles with errors handling.

I've made a custom Request:

```
  public function rules()
{
    return [
        "name" => "required|min:3|max:50|string",
        "price" => "required|numeric",
        "visibility" => "required",
        "description" => "required|string|min:10|max:50",
        "image_url" => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        "genre" => "required"
        
    ];
}
```

In my controller i have:

```
public function store(dishValidate $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    $file = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('public')->put($file->getFilename() . '.' . $extension,  File::get($file));

    $dish = new Dish;
    $dish["name"] = $data["name"];
    $dish["description"] = $data["description"];
    $dish["price"] = $data["price"];
    $dish["visibility"] = $data["visibility"];
    $dish["image_url"] = $file->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;

    $dish->getRestaurant()->associate(Auth::User()->getRestaurant->id);
    $dish->getGenre()->associate($data["genre"]);
    $dish->save();
    
    $item = "Hai creato un nuovo piatto con successo!";
    return route("success", compact("item"));
    
}
```

And in my blade:

```
    @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
```

I can't seem to have access to any errors. Is there also a way to keep input if validation fails?

Comment: Have you change default value for authorize() function to true? By default CustomerFornRequest comes with false value in Laravel.

Comment: Yes it's on true

Answer (score 1):

you can define validation rules like this.

**Method:-1**

```
$request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'img' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
    ]);
```

then in blade view file, you will return errors array using $error->all()

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Or You can also define it like this below another method( **for get validation error in controller function**),

**Method:-2**

step:1- include validator class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

step 2: define rule in controller function

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);
print_r($$validator->messages());
```

If you want to make validation in API I recommend use method-2.

Comment: I would like to keep the code clean and use a custom Request. There's not way to access error using Request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793716/how-add-custom-validation-rules-when-using-form-request-validation-in-laravel-5 check out this question, I hope this one helps to you

Comment: `dishValidate $request` this contain validation. We don't define it again in the controller with `Validator::make($`

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Apparently i'm stupid and i spent 1.5 hour in the wrong blade file.

Everything works fine with a custom Request.